# How to compute estimated variance for each disparity value?

Tags: stereo-vision, disparity

I am trying to implement the paper titled  **Free Space Computation Using Stochastic Occupancy Grids and Dynamic Programming**<sup>Herńan Badino, Uwe Franke, Rudolf Mester</sup> available at [this link](http://www.vision.jhu.edu/iccv2007-wdv/WDV07-badino.pdf)

The overview (section 2 first para) states the following :

> The stereo algorithm corresponding to the Stereo Computation block is not constrained to a
> specific implementation. The **only requirement is computation of enough disparity
> measurements to capture all relevant objects in a scene**. The stereo algorithm
> generates a disparity and a variance image. The variance image contains the **estimated
> variance of each measured disparity**.

The above statement confuses me as it does not quantify but uses the term **enough**.
In order to proceed, in my implementation I'm using dense disparity so that it is *enough*.

I do not know how to compute the estimated variance of each measured disparity?

I can compute the variance of a population using the standard formula for second moment, but  how to estimate variance of each sample point? Kindly help.